# Google Apps Script - Still struggling with looping through rows

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I'm still struggling with understanding loops.

I have a script that calculates the distance in kilometers between two addresses. At this point it only calculates the distance at row 12 and put the result in column C, row 12.

```
Start           End           Total km's      
address one     address two   16,283
```

Code (found on the web):

```
function GOOGLEMAPS() {

  var start_address = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A12').getValue();
  var end_address = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B12').getValue();

  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  var keerduizend = meters / 1000;

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C12').setValue(keerduizend);

}
```

The final result should be that it can calculate all distances that are put in the sheet:

```
A               B             C
Start           End           Total km's      
address one     address two   16,283    
address two     address one   16,283    
address three   address four  16,283    
address five    address six   16,283    

                Total        SUM(C12:C15)
```

It should not matter if there are 4 addresses or 40 and users should be able to add rows (between the last row with an address and the row with Total. As I'm still struggling with understanding loops I don't see how to achieve this.

Can someone explain to me how to achieve this?

**Edit**

Thanks to Diego the first part of the script works:

```
function GOOGLEMAPS() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var start_addresses = sheet.getRange('B12:B26').getValues(); // [["address one"], ["address two"], ["address three"], ["address five"]]
  var end_addresses = sheet.getRange('D12:D26').getValues(); // [["address two"], ["address one"], ["address four"], ["address six"]]

  var distances = []; // This will store all of the distances

    for (var i = 0; i < start_addresses.length; i++) {
    var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
    if (start_addresses[i][0] != "" && end_addresses[i][0] != "") {
      mapObj.setOrigin(start_addresses[i][0]);
      mapObj.setDestination(end_addresses[i][0]);
      var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

      var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

      var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

      var keerduizend = meters / 1000;

      distances.push([keerduizend]);
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange('E12:E26').setValues(distances);

}
```

Still get's an error

```
The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 3, but the range has 15. (line 30, file 'Code')
```

But I will try to figure this one out by myself first.

Comment: Maybe because var start_address = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A12').getValue();
  var end_address = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B12').getValue(); is selecting only one value??

Comment: Yeah that is a problem but I don't see how to put multiple values from that in the rest of the script.

Comment: Have a look at the Google Doc, getValues()

Comment: var start_address = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B12:B26').getValues(); gives values from that range but I don't know how many routes an user is going to put in the sheet. So I need to loop through the address columns and put the outcome of the calculation at the right row. But the loop needs to stop when the row with total appears (otherwise it will give an error I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read at all of the values in the range "A12:B15", you should use [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). If you look at the documentation, you'll see that it returns a two-dimensional array. The first element in the array is the row, and the second element is the column. Something like this:

```
       0      1
0 [ ["A-1", "B-1"] ]
1 [ ["A-2", "B-2"] ]
```

So the address of A-1 is `[0][0]`; the address of A-2 is `[1][0]`; the address of B-1 is `[0][1]`; and the address of B-2 is `[1][1]`. You can use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to read the value at each address. Look at the code below and try to figure it out on paper, then run it in the editor.

```
function test_forLoop() {
  var data = [["A-1", "B-1"], ["A-2", "B-2"]];
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.length; rowIndex++) {
    for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < data[rowIndex].length; columnIndex++) {
      Logger.log(data[rowIndex][columnIndex]); // Will print: "A-1", "B-1", "A-2", "B-2"
    }
  }
}
```

That's a very brief introduction, but let's return to your code. You can call `.getValues()` on the Column A range and the Column B range, and then loop through those values to calculate the various distances. Finally, you can use [`.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to print the results to Column C.

```
function GOOGLEMAPS() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var start_addresses = sheet.getRange('A12:A15').getValues(); // [["address one"], ["address two"], ["address three"], ["address five"]]
  var end_addresses = sheet.getRange('B12:B15').getValues(); // [["address two"], ["address one"], ["address four"], ["address six"]]

  var distances = []; // This will store all of the distances

  for (var i = 0; i < start_addresses.length; i++) {
    var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
    if (start_addresses[i][0] != "" && end_addresses[i][0] != "") {
      mapObj.setOrigin(start_addresses[i][0]);
      mapObj.setDestination(end_addresses[i][0]);
      var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

      var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

      var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

      var keerduizend = meters / 1000;

      distances.push([keerduizend]);
    } else {
      distances.push([null]);
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange('C12:C15').setValues(distances);

}
```

There are multiple ways to do this, but in order to help you understand it more easily, I chose to make as few changes to what you wrote. If you understand it, then please continue thinking about how you might improve it. For example, what if you selected columns A and B at the same time (`sheet.getRange('A12:B15')`)?

Comment: thank you for the help. I will play around with the code you gave me. I understand how I can get multiple values with getValues but I struggle with the part after that. That is because I don't complete understand what happens in the loop.

Comment: It gives an error at mapObj.setOrigin(start_addresses[i][0]);, invalid argument. If I use the logger I see that start_addresses returns 4 times all the values in column A (in the for loop). So it returns the whole range 4 times (but 3 rows are filled).

Comment: @NinaBakker What value of `start_addresses[i][0]` returns the error?

Comment: The error occures at mapObj.setOrigin(start_addresses[i][0]);, I think because start_addresses contains 4 arrays with all the adresses in it. mapObj needs one array with the addresses. I will update my question so I have more space to explain what happens.

Comment: @NinaBakker Does `start_addresses` include empty values? You wrote `[[address one], [address two], [address three], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []`. Is it _actually_ showing the empty brackets `[]`?

Comment: yes but that rows are not filled ;). `var start_addresses = sheet.getRange('A12:A26').getValues();` << the user can fill in 2 addresses or 40... depends on how many times they traveled that month. But for now I use A12:A26, sorry for the misunderstanding here.

Comment: @NinaBakker Take a look at the code in my answer. I just modified it to check if the addresses or empty.

Comment: you are a genius. Only problem now is that the .getRange().setVealues() at the bottom gives an error. The problem occures of not all rows are filled: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 3, but the range has 15. (line 30, file 'Code'). I will first try to figure it out myself.

Comment: @NinaBakker Fixed with `distances.push([null])`